# Why does strtod() with DBL_MIN give ERANGE?

Tags: c, floating-point, strtod

This program calls strtod() on the first command line argument and prints the returned value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  errno = 0;
  double d = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
  int errno_sav = errno;

  printf("string = %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("d = %.*e = %a\n", DBL_DIG + 2, d, d);
  printf("errno = %d\n", errno_sav);
  printf("DBL_MIN = %.*e = %a\n", DBL_DIG + 2, DBL_MIN, DBL_MIN);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2 or Linux Mint 17 Qiana with an argument of `2.22507385850720138309e-308`, corresponding to the smallest representable<sup>1</sup> double value (DBL_MIN), it gives the output I expect:

```
string = 2.22507385850720138309e-308
d = 2.22507385850720138e-308 = 0x1p-1022
errno = 0
DBL_MIN = 2.22507385850720138e-308 = 0x1p-1022
```

However, on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 with the same argument<sup>2</sup>, errno is set to ERANGE:

```
string = 2.22507385850720138309e-308
d = 2.22507385850720138e-308 = 0x1p-1022
errno = 34
DBL_MIN = 2.22507385850720138e-308 = 0x1p-1022
```

**Is the second behaviour valid, and if so why?**

---

Footnotes:

1. Since DBL_MIN is representable I think this question is different from "[Odd behavior when converting C strings to/from doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8794576/2319122)" where the value converted had underflowed.
2. On SUSE if I run the program with an argument of `2.22507385850720138310e-308` then errno is set to 0.  (And if I run the program with an argument of `0x1p-1022` then errno is also set to 0.)

Comment: Rather than `printf("d = %e\n", d);`, use `printf("d = %.*e\n", DBL_DIG + 2, d);` to show `d` to sufficient precision.  May also want to use `printf("d = %a\n", d);` for exact output.

Comment: Both systems `2.22507385850720138e-308`.  I'll modify the program to show these.

Comment: Note also that your input number is certainly *not* exactly representable, as can be determined quickly by sight. Given a proper fraction greater than zero and with a finite binary representation, the decimal representation of that fraction is also finite, and the least-significant non-zero digit of its decimal representation is 5.  Since the least-significant decimal digit of *your* number is 9 (and this is in the fractional part of the number), the fractional part, and thus the whole number, does not have a finite binary representation.

Comment: Note about last edit: post now discusses 3 different strings `...138309e-308`,  `...138310e-308`, `...138e-308` unlike the original  `...138309e-308` used consistently.

Comment: @chux - thanks, I have amended it with the output from the program run with the correct argument `...138309e-308`.  (The format `%.*e` does still return `...138e-308` for both d and DBL_MIN.)

Comment: You should read the value of `errno` before invoking `printf()`. `printf()` or any if the functions it invokes might change the value of `errno`.

Comment: @chqrlie - thanks, I've fixed that.  (The output is unchanged.)

Answer (score 3):

The input value 2.22507385850720138309e-308 is smaller than the exact value of `DBL_MIN` (2<sup>-1022</sup>). A larger decimal expansion is:

```
2.225073858507201383090232717332404064219215980462331830553327416887204434813918...e-308 v.
2.22507385850720138309e-308
```

So technically this results in underflow.

The C 1999 (7.20.1.3) states that in this case:

> If the result underflows (7.12.1), the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  E.g. to confirm in `bc` use `scale = 1000 ; 2^(-1022) - 2.22507385850720138309 * 10^(-308)` and observe that the result is greater than zero.  Thanks!

Comment: Why then don't they #define DBL_MIN as the apparently less problematic value `2.22507385850720138310e-308`?

Comment: Note that SUSE's strtod() manpage says: "If the correct value would cause underflow, zero is returned and ERANGE is stored in errno.".  So its behaviour seems consistent with the C standard but not its own documentation!

Comment: @BenC The smallest normalized `double` is `2.225073858507201_38309...e-308`  the next larger value is `2.225073858507201_87715...e-308`  `double d = 2.225073858507201_38310e-308` would get the value `2.225073858507201_38309...e-308`.

Answer (score 3):

As I read the C spec, this is not correct behavior.

`strtod()` refers to 7.12.1:

> **7.12.1 Treatment of error conditions**
>   The result underflows if the magnitude of the mathematical result is so small that the mathematical result cannot be represented, **without extraordinary roundoff error**, in an object of the specified type. C11 §7.12.1 6

Although, mathematically,  input strings are less than `DBL_MIN`,...

```
text
2.22507385850720_138e-308       // later post
2.22507385850720_138309e-308    // original post
DBL_MIN
2.22507385850720_13830902...e-308
```

... the conversion to `(double) DBL_MIN` is not with extraordinary roundoff error.  Value should convert to `DBL_MIN` without setting `errno`.

For reference, other nearby `double` are shown.

```
2.22507385850720_08890245...e-308  nextafter(DBL_MIN, 0.0),if sub-normals allowed, else 0.0
2.22507385850720_13830902...e-308  DBL_MIN
2.22507385850720_18771558...e-308  nextafter(DBL_MIN, 1.0)
```

---

I suspect the underlying code simple performed the conversion with extend precision like `long double` and then tested if the `long double` result was less than `DBL_MIN` rather than considering the edge conditions.